C# - How can I (de)serialize internal classes (from)to XML with attributes?
I want to (de)serialize internal classes.
internal class Data
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public List<DataWithAttribute> DataList { get; set; }
}

internal class DataWithAttribute
{
    public string? FirstAttribute { get; set; }
    public string? SecondAttribute { get; set; }
}

to get xml
<Data>
    <Name>Some name</Name>
    <Type>Some value</Type>
    <DataList>
        <DataWithAttribute FirstAttribute="some value" SecondAttribute="some value" />
        <DataWithAttribute FirstAttribute="some value" SecondAttribute="some value" />
        <DataWithAttribute FirstAttribute="some value" SecondAttribute="some value" />
    </DataList>
</Data>

I cannot write real code and data (because NDA)
I tried XmlSerializer, but It requires public classes.
So, I tried DataContractSerializer: it works with internal, but it doesn't support attributes.

what exactly do you mean by "attributes"? As in <Data FirstAttribute="1" SecondAttribute="2"/>? In that case I think you need to rethink your structure, as a list of similar attributes doesn't make much sense.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I want exactly two attributes, not a list.

but the property DataWithAttribute literally is a list. Anyway you cannot use complex types for xml-attributes. You have to serialize every attribute seperatly to a simple type.

You'd need to write your own serializer for this. I doubt there's any existing that can flatten your list of complex types to attributes in xml.

i update questions body

Use [XmlAttribute] on properties. Create DTOs.

@AlexanderPetrov can you give an example?

Related.

Why do you want to have internal classes at all? The moment you serialize something internal you expose it, this feels wrong.

Being pragmatic: make them public. You could serialize manually, but that's a massive PITA to do efficiently (the reader/writer API), and to do it the convenient way (DOM) has lots of intermediate overhead.

@Sinatr i want to make a library, and i dont want to expose data objects

sorry, brainfart. delete my comment

Why is the XML format a constraint (such as writing some properties as attributes) when you are exposing internal data? If any XML format will do it you can use my XML serializer (NuGet). See the result for your case.

I assume, as you said XmlSerializer works, but it doesn't because the class is not public.
I would recommend to write public dummy classes for this purpose:
public class DataDummy
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public List<DataWithAttribute> DataList { get; set; }
}

public class DataWithAttributeDummy
{
    public string? FirstAttribute { get; set; }
    public string? SecondAttribute { get; set; }
}

You should serialize and deserialize to them, and afterwards you do an explicit TypeConversion from and to your real Classes
For Example:
Data initialData = ...;
DataDummy initialDataDummyfied = (DataDummy)initialData;

or the other way around:
DataDummy deserializedData = ...;
Data usableData = (Data)initialData;

as long as the classes are the same, this should work.

this wouldn't work unless we override the explicit/implicit operator for each of those.
